# Angular 4 Return http response as interface with JSON as property

Tags: angular, typescript

I had a previously working service that used to only return the JSON response into my component (see second section for previously working code).  However, I am building in additional functionality into all of my components to have loading animations and error messages so I need the response.OK and response.status code as well.  I created this generic response interface to use in a global variable service I have as follows:

```
export interface GetResponse  {
    status: number,
    ok: boolean,
    json: any
}
```

I am using it in my service as follows:

```
   getInfoDeskTopic(topicUrl) {
        this.infoDeskData = [];
        this.http.get(topicUrl, this.options)
            .map(res => this.response = res)
            .map(res => this.response.json = res.json().resultSet.results)
        this.response.json
                .map(data => data
                    .forEach(item => {
                        let infoDesk = <InfoDesk>{};
                        infoDesk.Url = item.json.webUrl;
                        infoDesk.Date = item.date;
                        item.fields.forEach(item => {
                            if (item.id == 'publication') {
                                infoDesk.Publication = item.strings[0];
                            }
                            if (item.id == 'headline') {
                                infoDesk.Title = item.strings[0];
                            }
                        });
                        this.infoDeskData.push(infoDesk);
                    }))
                .map(data => data = this.infoDeskData)
            .map(items => items.slice(0, 5))
            .share();
        return this.response;
    }
```

And I am attempting to use it in my component as follows:

```
this.response = this.infodesk.getInfoDeskTopic(this.topicUrl);
this.news = this.response.json;
this.success = this.response.ok;
```

I have the variable in my component (this.response: any).  I receive the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for InfoDeskService: ([object Object], ?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1540)
```

Can any help me understand why I am getting an error? I feel like I am declaring something incorrectly perhaps, but I cannot figure out what the issue is.  Thanks

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

---

The following is what I had PREVIOUSLY and it was working fine (just for reference):

In my service:

```
   getInfoDeskTopic(topicUrl) {
        this.infoDeskData = [];
        return this.http.get(topicUrl, this.options)
            .map(res => res.json().resultSet.results)
                .map(data => data
                    .forEach(item => {
                        let infoDesk = <InfoDesk>{};
                        infoDesk.Url = item.json.webUrl;
                        infoDesk.Date = item.date;
                        item.fields.forEach(item => {
                            if (item.id == 'publication') {
                                infoDesk.Publication = item.strings[0];
                            }
                            if (item.id == 'headline') {
                                infoDesk.Title = item.strings[0];
                            }
                        });
                        this.infoDeskData.push(infoDesk);
                    }))
                .map(data => data = this.infoDeskData)
            .map(items => items.slice(0, 5))
            .share();
    }
```

And in my component:

```
this.news = this.infodesk.getInfoDeskTopic(this.topicUrl);
```

Comment: I have gotten rid of the error mentioned above by declaring the interface as the type for a variable in the service as opposed to in the constructor of the service.  However, now I am getting the error: "Cannot read property 'ok' of undefined" from when I am trying to set the variable in my constructor

Answer (score 0):

First if you use angular 4+, you should to use **HTTPCLIENT** vs **HTTP**.

Please, search the difference.. (You don't need to use .map)

Please look at this example:

```
interface interfaceJSON {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  company: string;
}

this.http.get<interfaceJSON>('apiUrl').subscribe(data => {
  console.log("Name: " + data.name);
  console.log("Email: " + data.email);
  console.log("Company: " + data.company);
});
```